# Does it cost copying data from one project to another project in BQ via Transfer feature?

Tags: google-bigquery

Good day,

it is unclear for me if it costs copying data from one project to another project in BQ via the Transfer feature?

Right now we have Scheduled Queries in place for this, but they exponentially increased our billing since we are querying large amounts of data every day while copying everything from Firebase BQ projects to our internal project. I am wondering if Transfer feature in BQ would decrease our billing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BigQuery Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/pricing) integrates more and more services.

When we talk about BQ to BQ transfer service it worths knowing the following:

- it works across regions
- it uses the free COPY operation
- it has the same limitations as [BQ Copy jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#copy_jobs).

So it doesn't charge you anything because it doesn't run a query, it doesn't export a table to cloud storage (so no files incur costs), instead it uses the COPY operation, which is free.

Answer (score 0):

Another option - You can copy a dataset within a region or from one region to another, without extracting, moving, and reloading data into BigQuery. You can copy the dataset one time or on a customized recurring schedule.

This feature is in Beta now. See more details in [Copying Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets)

As of **[Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#pricing)** for this feature:

There is no charge for dataset copying during the beta period.

At general availability, data copied between regions is billed at the same rates as pricing for Compute Engine network egress between regions.

BigQuery sends compressed data for copying across regions, so the GB billed might be less than the size of your dataset.

For more information, see BigQuery pricing.

Comment: are you sure this is working across regions? Because I never was able to accomplish that with the "transfer" menu, even today I've tried with US-to-EU, and the UI blocks you to do it.

Comment: confirming - it worked for me. it is still in beta, thus there are quite number of [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#quotas_and_limitations) that you might be hitting if it does not work for you